# Problem with result of a IF - AND function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to substract the last number of a 3 digit number (in fact a two decimal of comma number). I do this with the function:

```
=RIGHT(A1;1)
```

The result I got is correct.

After I need to "round" this number. If the number is between 2 & 6 it should be 4, otherwise it should be 9. I use this function for this:

```
=IF(AND((A2<7);(A2>1));4;9)
```

Strangely, the function is not working on the "RIGHT" function here first mentioned, but if I enter the value 'hardcoded' in a cell, and use the same function from here above it's working like a charm.
I was first thinking it had to do with the cell where the result was: text, number,... 
But even after changing it into text it's still not working correctly.

[image: printscreen]

Any idea what the problem could be ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: The RIGHT formula coverts the number to a string (text), you can see that text gets automatically aligned left in the cell and numbers are aligned right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `=RIGHT(A1;1)`, I think it's returning a text result. Try `=VALUE(RIGHT(A1;1))`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=IF(AND((RIGHT(A1;1)*1)>1;(RIGHT(A1;1)*1)<7);4;9)`